# Take until user clicks, drags or one value getting emitted

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to listen to observable only while one of these three events occurs:

- user clicks
- user drags
- one value getting passed through this observable I'm listening to

Currently I have written it like this:

```
this.pointsChange$
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(
                    merge(
                        this.eventService.pipe(flatMap(api => api.userClicked)),
                        this.eventService.pipe(flatMap(api => api.userDragged))
                    )
                ),
                take(1)
            ).subscribe(data => {
                // Do something with data
            });
```

It's working fine, however it looks a bit cumbersome to me, especially the combination of `takeUntil` and `take(1)`. Is there a method which can combine these two things?

Comment: You can create a custom operator for that if this pattern is repeatedly used

Comment: you want to listen or stop listening when the events listed above occure ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your code, but seems like you can

```
this.pointsChange$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(
            this.eventService.pipe(flatMap(api => merge(api.userClicked, api.userDragged))
        ),
        take(1)
      ).subscribe(data => {
      // Do something with data
    });
```